# Unhandled exception has occurred Error in VB based system,

Tags: vb.net, ms-access

I'm having this problem with a VB system that i'm developing for my degree project.

I don't have any errors in the list but i have a pop up message appearing stating "Unhandled exception has occurred in your application. If you click continue, the application will ignore the attempt to continue.... "

After the pop up displays, the exe hangs, and exits.

Here's the code. The code is meant to accept few details about the Admin and save it in a Microsoft Access DB called CQFOS with the table named adminrecords.

```
Imports System.Data.OleDb
Imports System.Configuration

Public Class adminadd

    'must put everytime, global bro
    Dim con As New OleDbConnection
    Dim cmd As New OleDbCommand

    Private Sub addadmin_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles addadmin.Click

        Dim TA As New CQFOSDataSet1TableAdapters.adminrecordsTableAdapter
        Dim cmd As New OleDbCommand
        Dim con As New OleDbConnection


        'Dim yourconnection As String = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("yourConnectionString").ConnectionString()
        Dim yourconnection As String = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("yourconnectionstring").ConnectionString

        'con = New OleDbConnection(yourconnectionString)
        con = New OleDbConnection(yourconnection)

        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text


        Dim connectionString As String = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("CQFOSConnectionString").ConnectionString
        con = New OleDbConnection(connectionString)

        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text


        cmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO adminrecords (AdminID,Name,DOB,Gender,Address,PhoneNo,Email) VALUES (@AdminID, @Name,@DOB,@Gender,@Address,@PhoneNo,@Email)"

        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@AdminID", adminidtxt.Text)
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Name", nametxt.Text)
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@DOB", dobtxt.Text)
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Gender", gendertxt.Text)
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Address", addtxt.Text)
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@PhoneNo", cnotxt.Text)
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Email", emailtxt.Text)

        cmd.Connection = con

        Dim RowsAffected As Integer
        con.Open()

        'rowaffected returns the number or row affected
        RowsAffected = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()

        Dim selectQuery As String = "Select FROM adminrecords"
        If RowsAffected = 1 Then
            MsgBox("New Record is saved.", MsgBoxStyle.OkOnly, "CQFOS")
        End If
        con.Close()

    End Sub

End Class
```

Any help is appreciated. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Try stepping through the code to isolate what line the problem occurs on. Put a breakpoint on the adminhome.Show() line and see what happens.

Comment: i removed the adminhome.hide sub itself. but still no error.

Comment: I cannot analyse your code a this time, but I find that debugging exceptions is very much easier when you configure VS to break on Thrown and unhandled CLR exceptions. To do this goto Debug => Exceptions and check the two boxes for the CLR exceptions. You're code will now break on the problem line, allowing easier debugging.

Comment: Where exactly is the error being thrown?

Comment: I'm getting this 2 Errors.

Error 12 Unable to copy file "obj\x86\Debug\Mark1.exe" to "bin\Debug\Mark1.exe". The process cannot access the file 'bin\Debug\Mark1.exe' because it is being used by another process. C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Microsoft.Common.targets 3390

Error 11 Could not copy "obj\x86\Debug\Mark1.exe" to "bin\Debug\Mark1.exe". Exceeded retry count of 10. Failed. C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Microsoft.Common.targets 3390

Comment: i've edited the codes above to my current codes, i still have the errors i've listed above. :(

Comment: @RayLight I have had instances where I had to delete the exe file in the bin\debug directory because of that same error, after doing so it was able to copy the file again.

Comment: @Mark Hall, just tried that. The build was successful, but the "Unhandled exception has occurred in your application. If you click continue, the application will ignore the attempt to continue.... " pop up box has appeared again. And btw, i've tried adding reference like a friend of mine suggested, but still no changes.

Comment: @RayLight is your error happening when you start your program or when you do a specific action.

Comment: @markhall when i build the application using build without debugging option

Comment: question solved. apparently, connectionsettings addname in App.config is different then the one i specified in the form's codes. haha. Took me a week to figure this out. thanks to everyone who chipped in their ideas!


p.s: if i have another question regarding this same codings, should i just ask here or post it in a new post? :)

Answer (score 0):

```
cmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO adminrecords   
(AdminID,Name,DOB,Gender,Address,PhoneNo,Email) VALUES
(@AdminID, @Name,@DOB,@Gender,@PhoneNo,@Address, @Email)"
```

Your PhoneNo and Address parameters are the wrong way round.